# How to improve screen resolution under Windows 98 working on a modern computer

Tags: resolution, windows-98

I have a computer with Windows 7 (starter) and alongside that I installed  Windows 98 on a small FAT partition on the hard drive (when I'm working in Windows 98, I boot the computer from a flash card).  Both OSs are working well.

My problem is that when working in Windows 98, I can't increase display quality to be better than 16-bit colors (800x600px).

I use default VGA:

```
Video Adapter Properties:
      Device Description                           Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
      Adapter String                               Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
      BIOS String                                  Intel Video BIOS
      Chip Type                                    Intel(R) GMA 3100
      DAC Type                                     Internal
      Installed Drivers                            igdumdx32 (8.14.10.1930)
      Memory Size                                  256 MB

    Video Adapter Manufacturer:
      Company Name                                 Intel Corporation

Monitor Properties:
      Monitor Name                                 Universal monitor PnP [NoDB]
      Monitor ID                                   DEL405A
      Model                                        DELL P190S
      Manufacture Date                             Week 25 / 2010
      Serial Number                                CHRYK06PDVPS
      Max. Visible Display Size                    38 cm x 30 cm (19.1")
      Picture Aspect Ratio                         4:3
      Horizontal Frequency                         30 - 81 kHz
      Vertical Frequency                           56 - 76 Hz
      Gamma                                        2.20
      DPMS Mode Support                            Standby, Suspend, Active-Off
```

My question is: How can I increase display quality to at least 24-bit colors? (a little program ASD Sea for DOS works well at that setting) Therefore, it seems there is no hardware problem causing this limitation.

*/My reason to have Windows 98 on modern computer is speed work. Like a cell–telephone, for example. I.e. “Switch on and speak”. Therefore I don’t want use any Virtual machines and other applications that are working under modern versions of Windows.

Comment: SciTech Display Doctor?

Comment: We really need to know the details of the computer - especially relating to the graphics card.

Comment: Hi Andrey - which graphics card do you have installed ..? It sounds like you are using the default vga within Win98...

Comment: -1 for not stating anything about trying to look for a driver

Comment: You are better to run W98 in a virtual machine like VMware.

Comment: My reason to have Windows 98 on modern computer is speed work. Like a cell–telephone, for example. I.e. “Switch on and speak”. Therefore I don’t want use any Virtual machines and other applications that are working under modern versions of Windows.

Comment: It looks like you created a second user account, which is why you were unable to edit your own question.  It will also interfere with commenting on your own thread and accepting an answer.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things worth considering - support for modern hardware on windows 98 is a bit of a pain. You'd be better off running this in a VM - I believe VMware has native drivers, but virtualbox does not. I ran this in virtualbox but chances are this should likely work on physical hardware as well.

There's a bit of software called scitech display doctor that acts as a sort of 'universal' driver that might work. It was shareware and the company is defunct - so a little googling may be needed to find more information. [There seem to be copies hosted here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060118061752/http://www.scitechsoft.com/products/ent/free_titles.html) with [officially released freeware codes](http://web.archive.org/web/20061228015158/http://www.scitechsoft.com/ftp/sdd/regcodes.txt) for it, though this is until 6.x. There's copies of a beta version of 7.0 floating around (which is essential on virtualbox - and may work if the older, freeware versions don't work) as well which might be of use. I'd give this a shot to see if it does what you want it to do.

This does rely on the video card working well in VESA mode, and your mileage may vary. I've broken an install getting this to work, and the best option is *abandoned, beta quality* software so I suggest backing up before you try this, and backing up often.

Comment: Comment by @Andrey (from suggested edit): I probed SciTech Display Doctor products for Windows and for DOS but without result; in vain. Anyhow the answer was the same: “No supported SuperVGA chip detected”. Meantime a little program ACD See for DOS works well at that setting. Therefore, it seems there is no hardware problem causing this limitation. My warm thanks for your response and consideration

Comment: Comment(2) by @Andrey: My reason to have Windows 98 on modern computer is speed work. Like a cell–telephone, for example. I.e. “Switch on and speak”. Therefore I don’t want use any Virtual machines and other applications that are working under modern versions of Windows.